# Can't print correct innerHTML message within a nested function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, scope, closures

I'm working on a recipes page where you have a series of buttons and posts that are interconnected. The buttons have names of recipe categories such as Pie and Cake. When you click on a 'Pie' button, you are only shown the posts that are categorized as 'Pie'. Both the buttons and the posts have data attributes that have their recipe category on there.

I am able to get this to work, however, I'm having issues for when you click on a recipe category button, and there are no corresponding posts. For this, I created an empty '#message' div that would output a message if there were no recipe posts found, and an empty string if there were recipe posts.

When I click on a recipe button that does have posts, I get the 'No Recipes' text in the message. Also weird that it looks like it's applying the correct message only to the last button/post which in this example is 'Cake'.

Can someone explain why this is not working? I get it's probably a scope/closure issue, but I'm unsure what's going on.

```
  //BUTTONS
  <section>
   <button class="recipe_button" data-btncategory="Pie">
      Pie
   </button>

   <button class="recipe_button" data-btncategory="Cake">
      Cake
   </button>
</section>

//POSTS
<div id="message"></div>

 <section class="recipe" data-postcategory="Pie">
     <h2>Pie Recipe</h2>
 </section>

 <section class="recipe" data-postcategory="Cake">
    <h2>Cake Recipe</h2>
  </section>


let posts = document.querySelectorAll(".recipe");
let postsArr = Array.from(posts);

let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".recipe_button");
let btnArray = Array.from(btn);

let message = document.getElementById("message");


btnArray.forEach((button) => {
    button.onclick = (el) => {
        let match = el.target.dataset.btncategory;
        postsArr.filter(function(post, i) {
            if (post.dataset.postcategory == match) {
                posts[i].style.display = "grid";
                  <-- message not working properly -->
                  message.innerHTML = "";
            } else {
                posts[i].style.display = "none";
                <-- message not working properly -->
                message.innerHTML = "Sorry No Recipes Available";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: look at how your filter is running. you'll always get ones that match and ones that don't - so both the if and the else code will always run - also, why are you using `.filter` if you never use the returned (empty) array

Comment: FYI: Don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't working with strings that contain any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: @JaromandaX  I used filter because I wanted to filter through the posts. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: but you are not filtering at all ... filter returns the filtered array - you don't do anything with the returned result ... note: in my answer, I also used filter ... that way you can get the length of the filtered array to conditionally set the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at how your filter is running. you'll always get ones that match and ones that don't - so both the if and the else code will always run

What you want to do is hide/display posts in the filter, returning true for displayed and false when hidden

That way, the resulting array length will be 0 if no match, and 1 or more if there is a match

Then another if/else after determining if there is anything displayed to show/hide the message

```js
let posts = document.querySelectorAll(".recipe");
let postsArr = Array.from(posts);

let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".recipe_button");
let btnArray = Array.from(btn);

let message = document.getElementById("message");

btnArray.forEach((button) => {
  button.onclick = (el) => {
    let match = el.target.dataset.btncategory;
    let found = postsArr.filter(function(post) {
      if (post.dataset.postcategory == match) {
        post.style.display = "grid";
        return true;
      } else {
        post.style.display = "none";
        return false;
      }
    }).length;
    message.innerHTML = found ? "" : "Sorry No Recipes Available";
  }
});
```

```html
<section>
  <button class="recipe_button" data-btncategory="Pie">
      Pie
   </button>

  <button class="recipe_button" data-btncategory="Cake">
      Cake
   </button>
</section>

//POSTS
<div id="message"></div>

<section class="recipe" data-postcategory="Pie">
  <h2>Pie Recipe</h2>
</section>

<section class="recipe" data-postcategory="Cake">
  <h2>Cake Recipe</h2>
</section>
```

Having said all that, the message would NEVER display `Sorry No Recipes Available` since your buttons guarantee that there will be one displayed

Comment: This worked for me! thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward way to make your idea work.
It uses an event listener with [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

See the in-code comments for further clarifications.

```js
// Identifies DOM elements
const
  btnsDiv = document.getElementById("btns"),
  posts = [...document.getElementsByClassName("recipe")],
  message = document.getElementById("message");

// Calls `filterPosts` when btnsDiv is clicked
btnsDiv.addEventListener("click", filterPosts);


// Defines `filterPosts`
function filterPosts(event){

  // Ignores irrelevant clicks
  if(!event.target.classList.contains("btn")){ return; }

  // Shows message while there is no match
  let match = false;
  message.classList.remove("hidden");

  // Remembers category
  const category = event.target.dataset.category;
  
  // Iterates through recipes
  posts.forEach( (post) => {

  // Hides recipe until it matches
    post.classList.add("hidden");

   // If recipe matches, shows it and notes the match
   if(post.dataset.category == category) {
      post.classList.remove("hidden");
      match = true;
    }
  });

  // If any match occurred, hides message
  if(match == true){
    message.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div id = "btns">
  <button class="btn" data-category="Pie">Pie </button>
  <button class="btn" data-category="Cake"> Cake </button>
  <button class="btn" data-category="Pasta"> Pasta </button>
</div>
<div id="message" class="hidden">Sorry No Recipes Available</div>

<div class="recipe hidden" data-category="Pie">
  <h2>Pie Recipe 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="recipe hidden" data-category="Cake">
  <h2>Cake Recipe 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="recipe hidden" data-category="Cake">
  <h2>Cake Recipe 2</h2>
</div>
```